# GET /index.php" 404

Tags: php, kubernetes, nginx

I am taking this feedback in my application.
I still can't find the reason
This application is running on Kubernetes

Log

```
Sep 29, 2023 @ 09:21:45.875 172.18.6.72 -  29/Sep/2023:09:21:43 -0300 "GET /index.php" 404

Sep 29, 2023 @ 09:21:45.871 172.18.6.72 -  29/Sep/2023:09:21:43 -0300 "GET /index.php" 404
```

Nginx Conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name exportacao.local exportacao.sandboxappmax.com.br;
    root /var/www/public;
   
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass api-export-service-php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile Nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine

COPY . /var/www

ARG NGINX_CONF_ENV
ENV NGINX_CONF_ENV ${NGINX_CONF_ENV}

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY .k8s/nginx/sites/api-export-service-${NGINX_CONF_ENV}.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: Could it be to do with firstly setting `try_files $uri = 404;` and then, under `location /` calling `try_files $uri $uri/` before `index.php`?